# MySQL query to get rows on specific date

Tags: mysql

ID |    STARTS     |  ENDS
1   |  2016-04-13  |  2016-04-14
2   |  2016-04-13  |  2016-04-15
3   |  2016-04-13  |  2016-04-15
4   |  2016-04-13  |  2016-04-16
5   |  2016-04-13  |  2016-04-19

I need to get the events on 2016-04-16 . So the result should be

4   |  2016-04-13  |  2016-04-16
5   |  2016-04-13  |  2016-04-19

What will be the mysql query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve data Mysql / Php where date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330771/retrieve-data-mysql-php-where-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `and`:

```
select *
from mytable
where starts <= '2016-04-16' and '2016-04-16' <= ends;
```

or `between`:

```
select *
from mytable
where '2016-04-16' between starts and ends;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need events on fixed date?

```
  select * from yourTable
  where STARTS between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-01 23:59:59'
  or ENDS between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-01 23:59:59'
```

EDITED, try this:

```
 select * from yourTable
  where STARTS >='2016-04-16' and ENDS <= '2016-04-16'
```

Comment: Tell me, what exactly you need. Do you have a table with 3 coluns right? ID, STARTS and ENDS and you want to list only events that start or end on single date? Because in your exemple, to show ids 4 and 5 will show events who heppens on the interval